# wxPython - centering text in wx.Notebook tabs?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython

I'm writing an application using wxPython for the GUI. I'm almost there, but there are some minor aesthetic things that are bugging me. Namely, at the end of the program (the 'results' frame), I have two nested notebooks. I'd like the text for the page-select tabs to be centered in said tab -- not left-aligned as is the default. I've been through the wxPython docs and searched my best, but with no luck. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've attached some minimal code showing the behavior I *don't* want (namely, left-aligned text in the tabs you select the notebook pages with), as well as a screenshot from the real-live app (which has, naturally, a bit more complicated interface -- but the solution, if it exists, should be something simple, I assume)

```
import wx

class ResultFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ResultFrame, self).__init__(parent, -1, title = "Results",
         style=wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.targets = ['these','are','some','strings']
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(1590,900))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainpnl.SetSize(wx.Size(1590,900))
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.ctrlsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.restart = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Start Over",\
         size=wx.Size(150,90))
        self.interp = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Help Interpreting\n"
         "Results", size=wx.Size(150,90))
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.mainpnl)
        for idx, tar in enumerate(self.targets):
            self.nb.AddPage(wx.Panel(self.nb, -1, size=wx.Size(850,820)), tar)
        self.ctrlsizer.Add(self.restart, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.ctrlsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.ctrlsizer.Add(self.interp, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.ctrlsizer, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frm=ResultFrame(None)
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: For example, the tab "LOD" should have "LOD" in the middle, not to the left.]

Answer (score 1):

In wxPython `Sizers` are used for laying out a window or collection of windows.
A notebook is no different, in that it too, can have its tabs laid out with a sizer or collection of sizers.
Sizers allow both positioning and alignment.

```
import wx

class ResultFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ResultFrame, self).__init__(parent, -1, title = "Results",
         style=wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        #self.targets = ['these','are','some','strings']
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(1000,-1))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.mainpnl = wx.Panel(self)
        self.mainpnl.SetSize(wx.Size(1590,900))
        self.mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.ctrlsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.restart = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Kubla Khan",\
         size=wx.Size(150,90))
        self.interp = wx.Button(self.mainpnl, wx.ID_ANY, "Samuel Taylor Coleridge\n"
         "Biography", size=wx.Size(150,90))
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.mainpnl)
#        for idx, tar in enumerate(self.targets):
#            self.nb.AddPage(wx.Panel(self.nb, -1, size=wx.Size(850,820)), tar)
        tab1 = wx.Panel(self.nb, -1)
        tab2 = wx.Panel(self.nb, -1)

        msg = '''In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
    Down to a sunless sea.
So twice five miles of fertile ground
With walls and towers were girdled round:
And there were gardens bright with sinuous rills,
Where blossomed many an incense-bearing tree;
And here were forests ancient as the hills,
Enfolding sunny spots of greenery.'''
        t1_text = wx.StaticText(tab1, -1, label=msg)
        t1_butt = wx.Button(tab1, -1, label="Next")
        t1sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        t1sizer.Add(t1_butt, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        tab1.SetSizer(t1sizer)
        self.nb.AddPage(tab1,"Stanza 1")

        msg = '''But oh! that deep romantic chasm which slanted
Down the green hill athwart a cedarn cover!
A savage place! as holy and enchanted
As e'er beneath a waning moon was haunted
By woman wailing for her demon lover!
And from this chasm, with ceaseless turmoil seething,
As if this earth in fast thick pants were breathing,
A mighty fountain momently was forced:
Amid whose swift half-intermitted burst
Huge fragments vaulted like rebounding hail,
Or chaffy grain beneath the thresher's flail:
And ’mid these dancing rocks at once and ever
It flung up momently the sacred river.
Five miles meandering with a mazy motion
Through wood and dale the sacred river ran,
Then reached the caverns measureless to man,
And sank in tumult to a lifeless ocean:
And ’mid this tumult Kubla heard from far
Ancestral voices prophesying war!'''
        t2_text = wx.StaticText(tab2, -1, label=msg)
        t2_pbutt = wx.Button(tab2, -1, label="Prev")
        t2_nbutt = wx.Button(tab2, -1, label="Next")
        t2sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_text, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_pbutt, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        t2sizer.Add(t2_nbutt, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        tab2.SetSizer(t2sizer)
        self.nb.AddPage(tab2,"Stanza 2")
        
        self.ctrlsizer.Add(self.restart, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.ctrlsizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        self.ctrlsizer.Add(self.interp, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.ctrlsizer, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        self.mainsizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainpnl.SetSizerAndFit(self.mainsizer)

        t1_butt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Next)
        t2_nbutt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Next)
        t2_pbutt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Prev)

    def Next(self, event):
        p = self.nb.GetSelection()
        p += 1 
        p = min(p, self.nb.GetRowCount())
        self.nb.SetSelection(p)

    def Prev(self, event):
        p = self.nb.GetSelection()
        p -= 1 
        p = max(0, p)
        self.nb.SetSelection(p)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frm=ResultFrame(None)
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes, I use sizers to lay out the content of each page, but I'm referring specifically to the small tab you click (unless using custom next/previous buttons like you did) to show a given page. In the screenshot attached to my original post, for example, there are two tabs in the right half of the frame - "LOD" and "Resuduals". I'd like to center the text in those tabs (not the panels they attach to) so, for example, "LOD" isn't way off to the side of the tab's area. Similar to how you can align text within a button to be dead center, to the left, right, up, down

Comment: I just noticed the tab handles in your screenshots DO appear centered (though possibly only because "stanza X" is longer than "LOD"), and that you're running Linux (or maybe macOS... I abandoned Apple altogether when they released the abomination known as Catalina). Maybe this behavior is system-dependent and there are no wx tools to control it? I would assume the layout of the tab handles/ears/whatever they're called would be just as easy to configure as, say, a button... but so far no such luck

Comment: Either, I'm going to have to pick through your questions word by word, checking punctuation to ensure that I know what the question really is, or, you'll need to be very specific. I have the feeling that we've been at cross purposes, more than once. To avoid all doubt on this point, concerning centering the text within the Tab heading itself, rather than the body of the tab, I have no idea. :)

Comment: Ah, my apologies if the question was misleading. It's hard to articulate what I'm referring to, especially when wxPython already mangles the common meanings of things like "Window" :) You are correct, though -- I'm asking specifically about aligning the text in the tab heading/label, *not* the text contained in the page of the notebook. It's not breaking the application, obviously, but just kind of ugly when your tab headers are much shorter than the width of the tab.